# Как сделать сообщение об ошибке рядом с полем ввода c#

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

Как сделать такое сообщение? Нигде не могу найти

Comment: WinForms или WPF? Исправьте вопрос, добавьте нужный тег.

Comment: Теперь нужно уточнить следующее: вы не знаете как пользоваться `ErrorProvider` или вас не устраивает визуально, то как он выводит сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: @Bulson не устраивает визуально

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, вам понравится простой Tooltip на событие TextChanged:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox TB = (TextBox)sender;
            int VisibleTime = 500;  

            ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
            if (/*если текст введен не верно*/)
            {
                tt.Show("Ошибка ввода", TB, 10, 20, VisibleTime);
            }

        }
```